# How can we get Realtime Sales Alerts

Tags: leads, sales

How can we get Real Time Sales Alerts and deals and how to Connect our salesforce to customers in just one click?

Comment: Pardot’s desktop application, LeadDeck can be helpful to get Real time sales alerts.

Comment: Please note that multiple punctuation is often considered impolite.